# Changing the format of the products in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I’m using the Woocommerce plugin. I want in the shop page to change the format of my products.
Right now, a product is shown as a “block” like the standard format for showing your products in WordPress.

Image
Product_Name1
Price
Add_to_Cart_button

Image
Product_Name2
Price
Add_to_Cart_button

But now I’m trying to get the products displayed as “lines”. Like this:

Product_Name1,                  Price,      Add_to_cart_button
Product_Name2,                  Price,      Add_to_cart_button
Product_Name3,                  Price,      Add_to_cart_button

The image is not needed and is already removed successfully. I searched [online](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) for solutions to change the format and found that in the CSS file, you can change the variable “display”  from "block" to “inline". But unfortuanly this didn't resulted in the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:inline-block` or `display:table-row` may be of help you

Comment: Where do I change this? Because it doesnt work, so I think I'm adjusting the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

Overiding the woocomerce templates can be one of the solution here:

If you'd like to customize the "Shop" page,

- Create the following folder: /wp-content/yourtheme/woocommerce/
- Copy the shop template file into your theme's /woocommerce/ folder.
- Now change the html code/ layout within the file as per your need

You can customize other woocomerce pages too by just copying them in your theme folder by maintaining the same folder structure.

Or In alternate way you can give a try with following plugin:
http://codecanyon.net/item/display-product-multilayout-for-woocommerce/6196331